# concatenating multiple Numpy arrays in dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have four dictionaries. And each value for each of the key in the dictionary is a 1D numpy array. I want to join all those numpy arrays into one. For example:

```
first dictionary =  {'feature1': array([0., 0., 1., 0.]),
'feature2': array([0., 1., 0., 0.]),
'feature3': array([1., 0., 0.,0.,0.,0.])}

 second dictionary = {'feature4': array([0.]),
'feature5': array([0., 0.]),
'feature6': array([0.023]),
'feature7': array([0.009]),
'feature8': array([0.])}

 third dictionary = {'feature9': array([  0.,   0.,   0., 912.,   0.,   0.,   0.]),
'feature10': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),}
```

The resultant final numpy should look like:

```
array([0., 0., 1., 0.,0., 1., 0., 0.,1., 0., 0.,0.,0.,0.,
      0.,0., 0.,0.023,0.009,0.,0.,
       0.,   0., 912.,   0.,   0.,   0.,0., 0., 0.,  0., 
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
```

As an example I've made this dictionaries smaller but I have unto 50 keys in each of the dictionaries. So basically I want to join all of the numpy arrays in my dictionaries.  How can I achieve this? Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just do:

```py
output = []

for dictionary in [firstdictionary,seconddictionary,thirddictionary]:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        output += list(value)
    
output_array = np.array(output)
```

Comment: Yes, I implemented a similar solution. Thank you!